Dimension of semisimple algebras over ground field
Let $A$ be a simple Artinian $K$-algebra. Is it true that if $K$ has characteristic zero, then $A$ is finitely generated over $K$?
By Wedderburn-Artin theorem $A \cong \text{Mat}_n(D^{op})$, so $[A: K]=n^2[D:K]$. But why $[D:K]$ is finite? Here $D=\text{End}_A(M) \subset \text{End}_K(M)$, where $M$ is a minimal left ideal of $A$.

No, it is not true, e.g. $A$ could be $K(t)$.
